# hadoop yarn: unknown user and group

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to figure out why my MR jobs are failing. One of the doubts I have is this warning in yarn resourcemanager's log:

```
2015-08-14 12:00:45,610 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for testing (auth:SIMPLE)
2015-08-14 12:00:45,624 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping: got exception trying to get groups for user testing: id: testing: No such user

2015-08-14 12:00:45,624 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: No groups available for user testing
2015-08-14 12:00:45,624 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.ServiceAuthorizationManager: Authorization successful for testing (auth:TOKEN) for protocol=interface org.apache.hadoop.yarn.s
erver.nodemanager.api.LocalizationProtocolPB
```

I don't have user '**testing**' configured anywhere. Also I couldn't find it mentioned in default configuration of yarn, mapreduce or other hadoop's subsystem.

Does anyone know where did this user come from?

Answer (score 1):

This error is likely related to HADOOP-12413 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12413).  You can see "user testing" and "user appattempt_" show up in logs.

Nick